# SQL query regarding Sequence

Tags: sql, database, sequence

I made a sequence in Net Beans. But when I tried to insert data in the table I get an error.

My code is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1


INSERT INTO Persons (ID,FirstName,LastName)
VALUES (seq_person.nextval,'Lars','Monsen');
```

The error is:

> [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X04] Column
>   'SEQ_PERSON.NEXTVAL' is either not in any table in the FROM list or
>   appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the
>   join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the
>   GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then
>   'SEQ_PERSON.NEXTVAL' is not a column in the target table.

Comment: oracle or mysql, which one DB do you use?

Comment: I am using netbeans internal database.

Comment: Do you know about `AUTO_INCREMENT` yet?

Comment: Actually I'm beginner.So I dont know,If you know plz let me know the code.

Comment: I don't know anything about netbeans, but I thought it's an IDE. What do you mean by "netbeans internal database"?

Comment: You have to first select `seq_person.nextval`, store it in a variable, then use it in the insert. Alternately add a default to `Persons`.`ID` - `ALTER TABLE Persons MODIFY ID DEFAULT seq_person.nextval;`

Answer (score -1):

The error message `Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X04` indicates you are using Derby DB not Oracle. That being the case you need to use Derby syntax for [getting the next value](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqljnextvaluefor.html). So your insert should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (ID,FirstName,LastName)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR seq_person,'Lars','Monsen')
```